# Possible to bulk-add children to a Firebase ref, each with individual priority?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to add a bunch of children to a Firebase ref simultaneously, each with an individual priority.

Adding each item separately with a unique priority is not ideal, because it generates a change event for each one, which can quickly cause performance problems in my client apps if there are hundreds occurring in quick succession.

Currently, I'm creating a Map with all the items and then passing that into setValue() on my ref to add them all at once.  However, as far as I know, there's no way to do this while giving each object its own priority.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution - if the objects being added have a field annotated with `@JsonProperty(".priority")`, this will be used as the priority when the object is added to Firebase, whether individually or party of a map, with no need to call `setPriority()`.  Handy to know!

Comment: Good stuff! How on earth did you find that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I figured it might work since that's how the priority looks when you export json, so I figured Jackson might parse it the other way too when it gets added, and it seems to do that.